# Does refreshing a filtered data extension reset the high watermark?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have an automation which runs every hour, checking to see if contacts have clicked or opened a number of emails. This runs a filter, which updates a data extension.

Is this interaction completely refreshing the data extension each time and re-setting he high water mark?

The reason I ask is that I am having the same contacts loop through my journeys every hour.

Is there a simple fix to this type of interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would. Filtered Data Extensions do not seem to play nice with Journey Builder. In my experience it not only resets the high water mark, but kicks out existing contacts once it has been refreshed (even if they still meet the criteria). Because of that I would only use filters when you are not refreshing the Data Extension while contacts may be active on any path.

I would use SQL queries instead. I'm not entirely sure of your use case, but you can add in new subscribers to the Data Extension that meet the criteria through the **Update** Add Method, and if needed update specific Data Extension fields that are set as exit criteria to remove subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

While creating an Automation studio, after specifying the query and click on next....there will be some options named "Append", "update" and "over right".

Just click on Over right so that every time it will have the latest one.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "overwrite"?

Comment: Yes overwrite..

Comment: if I use overwrite option on SQL Activity to refresh my DE, the overwrite reset the high water mark?